# Swift 3 Google Maps : _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices error

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, cocoapods

I followed [this article](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) to integrate `Google Maps` using `Cocoapods` in my iOS app. I am getting the following error.

[image]

My `podfile` looks like this

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'ClockIt' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ClockIt

  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'

  target 'ClockItTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ClockItUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: pod is fine, the issue is with your project settings. If you try to run the same pod with a demo project it will run. Try searching `Symbols not found for architecture armv7`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue with the following step

> Open the Build Phases tab, and within Link Binary with Libraries, add
>   the following frameworks:
>
> - GoogleMapsBase.framework
> - GoogleMaps.framework
> - GoogleMapsCore.framework
> - GoogleMapsM4B.framework (Premium Plan    customers only)
> - Accelerate.framework
> - CoreData.framework    CoreGraphics.framework
> - CoreLocation.framework
> - CoreText.framework
> - GLKit.framework
> - ImageIO.framework
> - libc++.tbd
> - libz.tbd
> - OpenGLES.framework
> - QuartzCore.framework
> - SystemConfiguration.framework
> - UIKit.framework

This step is also crucial if you are doing a pod install.

**This is not included in the [Google Map integration documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) for pod install.**